# BigDecimal.scale(0) put in method call works in not an appropriat way

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have the method:

```
public void send(Player player, String sum) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    addPlayerVariables(map, player);
    map.put("sum", sum);

    setVariableMap(map);

    setTemplateType(TemplateType.BIRTHDAY);
    sendMessage(player.getEmail());
}
```

and I call that method as follows:

```
send(player, newBonus.getBonusSum().setScale(0).toPlainString() + " " + account.getCurrency().getName());
```

and it works as if I ever didn't put the scale into `getBonusSum()`. For instance:

`newBonus.getBonusSum().setScale(0).toPlainString()` is `1500`
`newBonus.getBonusSum().toPlainString()` is `1500.0000`

and in the `send()` `1500.0000` is passed instead of `1500`. Why?

But If I split that into:

```
String str = newBonus.getBonusSum().setScale(0).toPlainString();
send(player, str + " " + account.getCurrency().getName());
```

it works fine. Could someone explain the reason?

Comment: Can you provide some more infos? What are the values and what results do you get?

Comment: @Tom, sure, could you see my question again?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the only place in your program where the `send` method is called?

Comment: I can't replicate this behaviour.  Your example should work fine, with 1500 being sent in the string.  Note, calling newBonus.getBonusSum().toPlainString() will still return 1500.0000 because you haven't altered the scale of the underlying object returned from getBonusSum(), just created a temporary new BigDecimal object to the send method (i.e. the one returned by setScale(0) ) and used its string representation to pass to the send() method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and it works as if I ever didn't put the scale into getBonusSum(). For
>   instance:

Because

```
newBonus.getBonusSum().setScale(0)
```

returns a new `BigDecimal` object
When you invoke `setScale` method it returns a new `BigDecimal` object and it doesn't modify the existing object. So  you need to re-assign it to newBonus like this

```
newBonus = newBonus.getBonusSum().setScale(0);
```

**Updated**
To make it more clear ,Let say  newBonus has a value 1500.0000 when you invoke

```
newBonus.getBonusSum().setScale(0).toPlainString()
```

Then a new BigDecimal variable is created with value `1500.0000` and `scale` 0 and then you  call `toPlainString` on it. Hence you see `1500` 
After that you execute the following statement

```
newBonus.getBonusSum().toPlainString()
```

Which will print `1500.0000` because neither `newBonus` value nor its scale was modified. Hence you see `1500.0000`

Comment: He don't have to, he can also pass this new variable directly to the method

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't saw his `newBonus.getBonusSum().toPlainString()` call.

Comment: Just to improve your answer you could add the standard `setScale()` implementation. I just looked at it just before.